# C++ Segmentation Fault when traversing linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program to find the `nth` to the last node in a linked list. The program produces the correct output, however, when I run the program I get a segmentation fault at the line `while(fast)`. When I debugged the program using print statements, I noticed `while(fast)` gets executed even when `fast` pointer is `NULL` (i.e. `fast` goes beyond the end of the list).

Any suggestions on how to fix the segmentation error?

Here's my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
public:
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

void insert(Node*& headPtr, int val) {
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = val;
    temp->next = headPtr;
    headPtr = temp;
}

Node* mth_to_last(Node* head, int m) {
    Node* fast = head;
    Node* slow = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        fast = fast->next;
    }

    while(fast) {
        fast = fast->next;
        slow = slow->next;
    }

    return slow;   
}

int main() {  
    Node* head;

    for(int i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {
        insert(head, i);
    }

    Node* res = mth_to_last(head, 4);
    cout << res->data << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the functionality of `mth_to_last()`? What does it do, semantically?

Comment: Returns the nth to last node in the linked list. So if the list was 1->2->3->4, and n is 2, it would return 3.

Answer (score 2):

It is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

You didn't initialize the `head` node before use ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/mrXsG7)):

```
Node* head = nullptr;
```

So, the `while` loop doesn't end because `head` contains some garbage value on start.

Also, you're not initializing `next` pointer of the first node either (`head`). Right now, it doesn't cause a problem because it's not being used. But, if you do start to use that, it'll cause problems i.e. more UB. So, you need to initialize that in the constructor e.g.:

```
struct Node {
    Node() : data{0}, next{nullptr} {}

    int data;
    Node* next;
};
```

Or, you can use [default member initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) like this:

```
struct Node {
    int   data {0};
    Node* next {nullptr};
};
```

Note that the default visibility of a `struct` is `public` so you don't need to mention that unless there are `private`, `public` and `protected` access specifiers in the same `struct`.

Also, in C++, you can do:

```
Node* next;
```

instead of

```
struct Node* next;
```

Here's an example with the above changes: https://godbolt.org/z/uVD76J

Relevant thread:

- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)